# Angularjs Google Map API Integration

Tags: angularjs, api, google-maps, controller

I'm trying to add a google map in angular JS... and have been struggling. 
I didn't want to use one of the angular dependencies, but simulate the 'async defer' on the [Google JS API site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map).

I'm pretty new to Angularjs but get the concept of keeping things assigned to the controllers scope. Pretty sure it's just something dumb, but not sure what... any help would be awesome :-)

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';
  app.controller('travelCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.injectScript = function(element) {
        var scriptTag = angular.element(document.createElement('script'));
        scriptTag.attr('charset', 'utf-8');
        scriptTag.attr('src', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY');
        element.append(scriptTag);
        return {
          link: function(scope, element) {
            injectScript(element)}}};

    $scope.initMap = function() {
            var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('kc-map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: uluru
          });
        };
    }]);
  })();
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="travelCtrl" id="kc-map"></div>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working ? Map isn't loading ?

Comment: Map's not loading. No error messages on the page, just doesn't load.

Comment: Do this: `angular.element(element).append(scriptTag);` MKEY seems to be invalid api key tho

Comment: Yeah, I just put that key in as a place holder :-P

Comment: Also... still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
  app.controller('travelCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.initialize = function() {
         $scope.mapOptions = {
             zoom: 8,
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.649907498685803, 88.36255413913727)
         };
         $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('kc-map'), $scope.mapOptions);
     }

     $scope.loadScript = function() {
         var script = document.createElement('script');
         script.type = 'text/javascript';
         script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD-5e8hV-uCuE1pEgTyMhk_gJJPK2f3F5A&callback=initialize';
         document.body.appendChild(script);
         setTimeout(function() {
             $scope.initialize();
         }, 500);
     }
    }]);
```

Add this to outer div.

```
ng-init="loadScript()"
```

Answer thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335835/how-does-the-google-maps-api-work-with-angularjs?rq=1)